# What's inside Hachikuji's bag?

Tags: monogatari-series

In the anime, Hachikuji always carries a large backpack everywhere. What's in the bag? And why she always carrying it? Did she also carry it in the LN?

(I only watched until episode 5 in Monogatari Series: Second Season, so I don't know if there will be any explanation about this.)

[image]

Comment: In addition to looper's answer, it's probably somewhat representing a snails shell in physical appearance - and guess what animal she's associated with~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, she also has the backpack in the Light Novel. When she decided to visit her mom after a long time, she put memories in there to make her mother happy.

Here's a quote from the Mayoi Snail Arc in the LN (BakaTsuki translation):

> She neatly bound her own hair and filled her favorite backpack full of old memories hoping to delight her mother with them.

.

> In the end she died with her backpack on, so she still carries it after her death.

Comment: Specifically these old memories were of her dad.